# AWS Lambda. Get RDS instance endpoint, connect to it, run SQL script and then delete with final snapshot creation

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I have one lambda which creates new RDS instance from snapshot and I need another lambda to connect to this RDS instance and run SQL script on it. I'm trying to do it with this code:

```
import boto3
import pymysql
import sys

region = 'eu-west-1'
user = 'username'
password = 'password'
snapshot_name = 'snapshot'

source = boto3.client('rds', region_name=region)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    try:
        dbs = source.describe_db_instances(DBInstanceIdentifier='new-db-instance')
        rds_host = dbs.get('DBInstances')[0].get('Endpoint').get('Address')
        conn = pymysql.connect(host=rds_host, port=3306, user=user, passwd=password, db='mysql', connect_timeout=5)
        with conn.cursor() as cur:
            cur.execute("some_SQL_script")
    except Exception as ex:
        print ex
```

But I'm getting timeouts even with 5 minutes lambda without any exceptions.

Comment: after 300 seconds any lambda function will timeout: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html